# How to optimize Cookie Parsing?

Tags: javascript, optimization, parsing

I have written this code for cookie parsing. Can anyone tell me what optimizations we can do in this or what can we do to make it more concise?

```
function parseCookies(cookies) {
  var cookie,
    cookieParts,
    parsedCookies = [];

  if (!cookies || !cookies.length) {
    return null;
  }

  // Remove domain from each cookie to decrease the size of cookie (Not needed)
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    cookie = cookies[i];
    cookieParts = cookie.split(';');

    for (var index2 = cookieParts.length - 1; index2 >= 0; index2--) {
      var pair = cookieParts[index2],
        key = pair.split('=')[0];

      if (key && key.trim().toLowerCase() == 'domain') {
        cookieParts.splice(index2, 1);
      }
    }

    cookie = cookieParts.join(';');
    parsedCookies.push(cookie);
  }

  return parsedCookies;
}
```

Comment: Could you add examples of input and output? As far as I can tell, this isn't so much a parser but rather a sanitizer, since it returns the same format, just with some stuff removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I wrote in my comment, the function you've got isn't really a parser. Yes, it parses the strings you pass it, but that's not its purpose, as far as I can tell. Parsing is a byproduct of the actual purpose, which seems to be to sanitize the strings by removing the `domain` key/value pair.

Now, if you're just looking to remove that key/value pair, you could simply do

```
function sanitizeCookies(strings) {
  return strings.map(function (cookieString) {
     return cookieString.replace(/\bdomain\s*=[^;]*;?/ig, "");
  });
}
```

Like @tomdemuyt, I'm using `Array.map()` so you won't get `null` back if you pass it an empty array; you'll just get another empty array (and, frankly, that makes more sense, I think).

Answer (score 1):

This question is a great candidate for using Array.map and Array.filter. That is, if you are willing to return [] instead null if cookies is not provided.

Basically you map cookies to a new array which has modified cookies, and you filter out the value from the cookie that you don't want.

I did not test this, but something like this ought to do the trick:

```
function parseCookies(cookies) {

  cookies = cookies || [];

  return cookies.map( function(cookie)
  {
     return cookie.split(";").filter( function( value )
    {
      return !( value && value.trim().toLowerCase().substring(0,7) == "domain=" )
    }).join(";");
  });
}
```